# Loading Add-on list in android sdk manager

Tags: android

Whenever I start SDK manager in Add-on list, it always show the error `"Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list.xml`, `reason: File not found"` due to the fact that I do not have an installed SDK platform to work upon. I have tried everything, please help me.

Comment: What is "everything"? If you have indeed tried everything, then nothing we say can help you.

Answer (score 1):

if i try to open this link inside my browser i get an error 404, so this file does not exist.
maybe you should download a newer version of the android sdk, u can get it here [android sdk](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

On the navigation bar menu on the top, click on Tools / Manage Add-On Sites...

Then go on the right hand tab on the new window. (User defined sites)

Delete the site that says https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list.xml and click close in the bottom right.

Or update the entire SDK, that will work just as well.

Hope this helps :-)